# Cannot build library project Bintray Gradle - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am still trying to get my gradle script work, I have expolered all logs and it seems that there are some classes are missing. Here is message.

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':horizontalrecyclerview'.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(Imper

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenFactory
        ... 51 more
```

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
version = "1.0.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/CROSP/AndroidHorizontalRecyclerView'      // Homepage URL of the library
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/CROSP/AndroidHorizontalRecyclerView.git'   // Git repository URL
group = "com.github.crosp.horizontalrecyclerview"                      // Maven Group ID for the artifact

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'

}
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name 'Android Horizontal Recycler View with Headerr'
                description = 'Android Horizontal Recycler View with Header project for displaying horizontal list on Android '
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'crosp'
                        name 'Alexandr Crospenko'
                        email 'crosp@xakep.ru'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

// https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        // it is the name that appears in bintray when logged
        name = "crosp"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
        version {
            gpg {
                sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
                passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password") //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
            }
//            mavenCentralSync {
//                sync = true //Optional (true by default). Determines whether to sync the version to Maven Central.
//                user = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.user") //OSS user token
//                password = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.password") //OSS user password
//                close = '1' //Optional property. By default the staging repository is closed and artifacts are released to Maven Central. You can optionally turn this behaviour off (by puting 0 as value) and release the version manually.
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone already had such problem or know the way to solve it ? Please help, because I cannot get it work whole day already.
Thx in advance.

Comment: It seems that this class has been removed. Try to bump gradle version.

Answer (score 14):

I am doing the same thing (upload my aar to bintray) and I have the same problem.

I am aware that it is occurred in gradle library, so I change my gradle verion from 2.4.0 to 2.2.1 by this way

> File -> Project Structure (or trigger hotkey `command + ;`) -> click the `Project` in the left list in the dialog -> input 2.2.1 in the Gradle textedit box.

I solve this error by this way.Look for the note part in file [README.md](https://github.com/rogerAce/myProject/blob/master/README.md).

Hope this can help you.

ps:If you want to use gradle 2.4.0, you should config android-maven-plugin version to 1.3 in classpath in the project root build.gradle as :

`com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3`